# Keeping same number of child processes

Tags: c++, linux

I have the following program that creates a certain number of child processes, say 20.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define NITER  20

int main()
{
   pid_t pid;
   int i;

   printf("\nExemplo de aplicacao 02 da funcao fork()\n");
   printf("Processo pai inicial tem PID=%5d\n", (int) getpid());
   for(i=1; i<=NITER; i++) {
      pid= fork();
      if ( pid==-1 ) {
         perror("Erro na funcao fork()");
         exit(1);
      }
      if ( pid ) {
         /* pid>0, codigo para o processo pai */
         printf("Codigo do Pai  (i=%2d):  PID=%5d  PPID=%5d\n", \
            i, (int) getpid(), (int) getppid());
      }
      else {
         /* pid=0, codigo para o processo filho */
         printf("Codigo do Filho(i=%2d):  PID=%5d  PPID=%5d\n", \
            i, (int) getpid(), (int) getppid());
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I would like to change it, in such a way that I make sure I only have 4 child processes running at the same time. It needs to check if one of the 4 ended and create a new one automatically. This until the number of 20 has been reached. Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start your 4 children, and then use [`wait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) to know when a child exits and relaunch another one.

---

EDIT - **Example** (not tested but should gives you some hints):

```
int main ()
{
    pid_t pid;
    int process_count = 0, global_process_count = 0, max_process_count = 20;

    while (global_process_count < max_process_count)
    {
        while (process_count < 4)
        {
            if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
            {
                perror("fork");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            else if (pid == 0)
            {
                // Child process
                exit(EXIT_SUCESS);
            }
            ++process_count;
            ++global_process_count;
        }
        while (waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0)
            --process_count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thks. I am not too familiar of the wait options. Could you pls show in the code?

Comment: See my edit. Not tested but should gives you some hints.

Comment: +1 but you probably want waitpid > 0 or you will keep decrementing process_count when there are existing children that haven't changed state.  No way to avoid the constant polling of waitpid w/o a sleep or changing it to use a signal handler.

Comment: @Duck You're right, from [man wait](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?waitpid+2): _[...] if WNOHANG was specified and no child(ren) [...] has yet changed state, then 0 is  returned_. I'll change that.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I am going to try it.

Comment: It seems that the waited is always giving -1 and it exit the while loop with the waitpid function. Can you help out?

Comment: Just one quick add. All processes ended too quickly that is why I was getting -1. Need to check if there are childs running, any help?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [semaphore](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_wait), it does exactly what you are trying to do. There is also example code.

[Here](http://www.codeincodeblock.com/2012/12/using-semaphore-to-synchronize-multiple.html) is a description on how to use a semaphore.